# Swift - how to get ios device current language

Tags: ios, swift, locale

My device running iOS 12 and has English language as its primary language and Hebrew as it's secondary language.

Now I'm opening my application with English as it's Base localization.

In the application I have list of three languages: English, Hebrew and French.

At first the attribute `Locale.preferredLanguages` result is: ["en-IL", "he-IL", "fr-IL"]

If I want to localize my entire application without to change the operating system language I'm changing only `AppleLanguages` array on `UserDefaults` like that:

```
func currentAppleLanguage() -> String {
    return (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? NSArray)?
        .firstObject as? String ?? ""
}
func setAppleLanguageTo(lang: String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set([lang], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
}
```

And after I make that change I'm restarting my application and the language changes.

The thing is after I change `AppleLanguages` at `UserDefaults` for example to `"he"`, the `Locale.preferredLanguages` attribute turns into: `["he"]`

So now I don't have the `preferredLanguages` fallback localizations that set on the operating system at the settings application.

Moreover, I'd like to now how can I get the current running device language on the operating system even after I change the application language with `AppleLanguages` like facebook does

[image: Facebook localization screen]

I'd like to mention I notice that when I edit the running scheme of Application Language to another language it changes the AppleLanguages as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing the array of "AppleLanguages" with just a single value, update the existing list so the specified language is moved to the top.

```
func currentAppleLanguage() -> String {
    return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")?.first ?? ""
}

func setAppleLanguageTo(lang: String) {
    // Get the current list
    var languages = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages") ?? []
    // Get all locales using the specified language
    let matching = languages.filter { $0.hasPrefix(lang) }
    if matching.count > 0 {
        // Remove those entries from the list
        languages.removeAll { $0 == lang }
        // Add them back at the start of the list
        languages.insert(contentsOf: matching, at: 0)
    } else {
        // It wasn't found in the list so add it at the top
        languages.insert(lang, at: 0)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(languages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
}
```

This keeps the full list. It just reorders the values so the desired language is first.

Comment: OK, it can be helpful, it answering my first question, but is there and way to save or get the current iOS system language that set on settings app like facebook does?

Comment: I don't use Facebook so I have no idea what you are referring to. But normally, an app uses Locale.current to to determine the user's locale settings, including language.

Comment: the screenshot in the post is from facebook language settings screen with my phone sets to English, the facebook app sets to Hebrew and the first option in the list shows `Match phone language` with subtitle in Hebrew tells `English (Israel)`